# Android canvas how to animate a drawn circle

Tags: android, canvas

Hi people I'm doing a Conect4 and I want to do that the circle fall since the pixel number 200 for example to the correspondent pixel or row. I did before animations in XML and I know how to animate the canvas but I didn't find a question to translate a circle to make the sensation that is falling.
Sorry if mi english is bad but I'm a 1 of Bachillerato Student of Spain.
I did this onTocuh and onDraw methods :

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void CaidaFicha () {
        ValueAnimator caidaFicha = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this,"caida",200,1000);
        caidaFicha.setDuration(10000);
        caidaFicha.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
        caidaFicha.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        caidaFicha.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        caidaFicha.start();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();
        anchoX = x;
        anchoY = y;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        /*Texto*/
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(80);
        canvas.drawText("CONECTA 4", 70, 130, paint);
        /*Separador*/
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5C5C5C"));
        canvas.drawRect(0, 200, 600, 210, paint);
        /*Tablero*/
        int radius = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.NFILAS; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.NCOLUMNAS; j++){
                if (game.estaVacio(i,j)){
                    color = Color.WHITE;
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawCircle(getPixelFromColumna(j), getPixelFromFila(i), radius, paint);
                } else if (game.estaJugador(i,j)){
                    paint.setColor(coloreado);
                    canvas.drawCircle(getPixelFromColumna(j), getPixelFromFila(i), radius, paint);
                } else {
                    color = Color.RED;
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawCircle(getPixelFromColumna(j),getPixelFromFila(i), radius, paint);
                }
            }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int fila;
        int columna;
        int pixel_x;
        int pixel_y;

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            pixel_x = (int) event.getX();
            pixel_y = (int) event.getY();
            fila = getFila(pixel_y);
            columna = getColumna(pixel_x);

            if (game.tableroLleno()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.fin_del_juego,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (game.sePuedeColocarFicha(fila, columna) != true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.nosepuedecolocarficha,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            if(pixel_y > 200){

                game.ponerJugador(fila, columna);

                if(game.comprobarCuatro(Game.JUGADOR)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha ganado " + nombreFinal,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(game.fin()) {
                        fragmento_dialogo dialogo = new fragmento_dialogo();
                        dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alert Dialog");
                    }
                }

                game.juegaMaquina();

                if(game.comprobarCuatro(Game.MAQUINA)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has perdido " + nombreFinal,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(game.fin()) {
                        fragmento_dialogo dialogo = new fragmento_dialogo();
                        dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alert Dialog");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you familiar with `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator`? if not, google them

Comment: okey I will search if I don't know so well how to use it I will return.

Comment: How I can do this part : set.setTarget(myTextView); with a circle drawn by canvas?

Comment: what it's set?  what properties are you using?

Comment: Now nothing, but I see this in an example :

Comment: ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myTextView, "backgroundColor", RED, BLUE);
        colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
        colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        colorAnim.start();

Comment: AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(myContext,
R.anim.property_animator);
set.setTarget(myTextView);
set.start();

Comment: And if  I do this how i say to the computer that I want to animate : canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,paint)?

Comment: and you can use any property you like: not only "backgroundColor", use "fooBar" for example

Comment: Yes but how I say that i want to animate this :canvas.drawCircle(getPixelFromColumna(j), getPixelFromFila(i), radius, paint);

Comment: you want to change position of the circle or radius, or both?

Comment: I want to make the circle that I draw with canvas.drawCircle... start in pixel 200 and make it fall where I touch on the screen. Change the position yes.

Comment: use something like this: ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myCustomView, "circleYPosition", 200, 1000)

Comment: Thank you, but If I put myCustomView i'm changing the canvas not the circle, isn't it?

Comment: The first argument that you pass to ObjectAnimator.ofInt is the View and inside the view is the onDraw and the onTouch so I think that if you animate the View the canvas will animate the canvas not the circle of the canvas.

Comment: Or I need to do another View to draw the circle?

Comment: no, just try with that `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myCustomView, "circleYPosition", 200, 1000)` and see what happens, of course setDuration() and start() it

Comment: nothing where I must write CaidaFicha(); to make it function?

Comment: what CaidaFicha ? what is it?

Comment: sorry, I edit my code now

Comment: Code Edited CaidaFicha traduction to enflish is : PieceFall I think.

Comment: so if you have your Animator start it somewhere and see what happens

Comment: I only need to start in in somewhere?

Comment: start it for example inside : if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

Comment: okey, sorry if i'm a bit silly but how i start it? writing caidaFicha.start()?

Comment: call CaidaFicha(), it creates an ObjectAnimator and starts it, isn't it?

Comment: no, nothing new pass

Comment: It just pust the piece where I touch like before

Comment: "nothing new pass"???

Comment: no, i don' understand

Comment: did you start that Animator?

Comment: yes, I started the animator

Comment: anithing, the app just crash in 10 sec more or less

Comment: crash? and what was in the logcat?

Comment: need a set method, but I don't know for what

Comment: So do that, otherwise such Animaor is useless

Comment: see minimalistic View here: https://codeshare.io/xdeiV

Comment: tahnk you, when I have a bit of time i will try to do this. At the afternoon I will reply you.

Comment: I understand to do it with 1 ball but did you see my onDraw?, see it and say me what I must do please. I should do a new View only for the circle?

Comment: you can draw in your View multiple number of circles, not only one

Comment: it's impossible to animate 1 circle, for example if I want to animate only the draw when estaJugador(i,j);?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean...

Comment: No problem I resolve it, the only problem that I have now is that i want that the circle stop in the pixel that I touch how I can do it?

Comment: use `android.animation.PointFEvaluator`

Comment: inside the class that extends view?

Comment: yes, use it for interpolation between startPoint and endPoint

Comment: just buy me a beer in my next incarnation...

Comment: jajaja, thank you a lot man , I aprecciate your help very much seriously

Comment: And if I want to change the color of the animation?